Particle-mesh method & energy conservation
Disclaimer: I'm a complete novice when it comes to computational physics but I want to learn more. As a starting point, I wanted to implement the particle-mesh method following Hockney's textbook.
I want to create a simple n-body simulation using the PM method (the bodies are in a gravitational field; I'm using leapfrog integration and nearest grid point assignment).
To have a point of reference, I also implemented it using PP (I used RK4 for integration).
When comparing the two methods (PP and PM) on a simple test case with just two particles, the shape of the trajectories traced by the particles using both methods is very similar.
However, the graph of the total energy vs. time indicates that something's wrong with my implementation of the PM method (I think).

This image (above) shows the total energy vs. time (to the left) and total momentum vs. time (to the right) graphs. As you can see the energy is steadily decreasing (the perturbation between 150 and 250 marks happens when the two bodies go past each other).
When I plot analogous graphs for the PP method, both the energy and momentum stay constant (see below).
Is this an expected behavior? Hockney's textbook only mentions (in ch. 2) that the increase in the total energy is to be expected, and indeed, making the timestep bigger causes the energy to grow over time.
Question: Do these results indicate that there's an error in my code? Or should I try to repeat the tests with a more sophisticated mass assignment scheme like cloud-in-cell?
